# Can't get DateTime.TryParseExact to work

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
string[] format = { "yyyy/MM/dd", "MM/dd/yyyy" };
DateTime valueDate;
value = value.Replace("-", "/");
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out valueDate))
{
    value = "TO_DATE(" + valueDate + ", 'yyyy-mm-dd')";
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Could not parse incoming date: " + valueDate);
}
```

---

So now I have a test case.
And value = '2013/01/21' after the replace statement replacing "-" with "/".

This should match the first format in the format string array.
But TryParseExact is not working and always goes to the else path.
Can anyone see any errors in this code?

Comment: Why not add two more formats to the array?

Comment: @SonerGönül the current culture is irrelevant the OP is passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Oh. And from the looks of things, you are concatenating SQL. It would be better to use a parameterized query and pass in the `DateTime` directly.

Comment: I just have tried your code and it parsed successfully.

Comment: Code works. You shoud check your input string if its really what your saying. Presumably you got some untrimmed whitespaces in there.

Comment: TryParseExact() will use midnight as the time when no time is in the requested formats.  Does "value" have a time other than midnight?

Answer (score 4):

It's not `TryParseExact` that's the problem, it's the value of your string. I say that because this little `scriptcs` script:

```
using System.Globalization;

string[] format = { "yyyy/MM/dd", "MM/dd/yyyy" };
DateTime valueDate;
var value = "2013/01/21";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out valueDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failure!");
}
```

prints `Success!`. So, in other words, this statement:

> **And value = '2013/01/21' after the replace statement replacing "-" with "/".**

literally cannot be correct.

As stated by James, it's very possible there is whitespace in the actual string value. There are a couple solutions: remove the whitespace or allow whitespace. To allow whitespace you could use `DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces` rather than `DateTimeStyles.None`.

Comment: it can be correct, there's probably just some extra whitespace in there.

Comment: @James, I'll give you that, but that also means it's *not correct* because `'2013/01/21  '` is **not the same** as `'2013/01/21'`, especially when using `TryParseExact` and a `DateTimeStyles.None`.

Comment: What I meant was the fact the OP is seeing the date has updated to use `/` instead of `-` but not necessarily realising the extra whitespace, it can be pretty subtle.

Comment: @James, that's a fact, it can be very subtle. And if it's whitespace (which is probably a good observation) then the OP could also use `DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces` too.

Comment: Ah, thanks Michael.
I put in your literal line setting my date and that worked. I had single quotes around the literal from another part of the build up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's your issue, but make sure you always escape out your forward-slashes when using date formats. A `/` character is not a literal slash, but rather your local system's [date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) (which is usually the forward-slash, but not always).

When using a format string, you escape a forward-slash with a real backslash, like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2012/12/31", "yyyy\\/MM\\/dd", null);
// or
DateTime.ParseExact("2012/12/31", @"yyyy\/MM\/dd", null);
```